# How to find out reasons for aborted queries in redshift?

Tags: amazon-redshift

I am trying to figure out the reasons/errors related to aborted queries where the aborted queries could be found out from the `stl_query` table. I used `stl_errors` for this but found out that the error context is related to `process id` not to specific query id. Is there any way I could find out the reason from one of the system tables present in redshift?

Answer (score 3):

Here is nice list of possible reasons, plus where - in which table - to find any info:

- https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/redshift-query-abort/

But, in my case it was not enough, as it turned out that connection sometimes was just closed without proper committing changes, and for that there is another set of where to check out such cases:

- https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/query-completed-with-no-updates/

The latter helped in my case as it just lead me to find the reason of mysterious aborted queries.

Happy hunting.